# Push Notification does not working on first time installation

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am getting stuck on push notification. When I am installing the app first time then the firebase notification does not trigger, but after killing one and open again app it's working fine.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().isAutoInitEnabled = true
        return true
    }


func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
      print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(fcmToken, forKey: "Token")
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
       
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }

     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
      
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        
    }
```

Comment: Any solution for this problem?